# Preseeding debian installation still asks for network card

Tags: debian-installer, preseed

I am using debian installer together with a preseed config-file to automate  installation steps.

Currently the network-card selection still shows up and I cannot find out why.

I have the following networking-related lines

```
d-i netcfg/choose_interface select auto
d-i netcfg/choose_interface select enp0s8
d-i netcfg/link_wait_timeout string 20
```

The selected interface-card is available in the dialog that appears and also when installation finishes:

```
$ sudo ifconfig
enp0s8: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
...
```

However the Debian installer still stops and forces me to choose the network-card to use.

How do adjust the preseed file to also perform this selection automatically?

Answer (score 2):

Ugh, warming up old stuff. But I just had the same problem and found the solution.

The issue is that the preseed file is loaded **after** the d-i performs network configuration (sic!). So when you get to the interface selection, the preseed anwsers are yet unknown.

So you need to add the relevant interface to the kernel commandline like so:

`auto=true priority=critical interface=enp0s8 url=http://host/path/to/preseed.cfg`

`interface` is an alias for `netcfg/choose_interface`
and you can thus (and should) remove all `netcfg/` entries from preseed file.

Comment: When you say "add to the kernel cli" how do you do that? Can you edit your answer to improve it? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The only option that I found was to remove all but one network interfaces of the VirtualBox machine, then the installer seems to automatically select this one.

Answer (score -1):

The answer by Johannes Spanier on 18 May 2020 solved this for me, with some slight adjustments.

I was using netboot.xyz (self hosted) so it was very easy for me to modify the menu to include the interface= keyword. netboot.xyz is an amazing, magical service which makes things like this incredibly simple.

I went to the web interface (netboot.myinternaldomain:3000), clicked on Menus, clicked on my custom menu (just a modified version of the default Debian menu) then found this section and updated the `set install_params` line (note: this is actually a customised copy of the default `:deb_preseed` section - I've modified it to hard code the URL on which I host my preseed file so I don't have to remember it or type it.

```
:deb_preseed_custom
set preseedurl preseed.myinternaldomain/preseed.cfg
set install_params auto=true priority=critical interface=auto preseed/url=${preseedurl}
goto deb_text
```

Instead of specifying a particular interface name, I used `auto` which worked perfectly and stopped the Debian installer stopping to ask which interface to use.